# Discord.js add roles if argument is from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make a command that gives a role from the array when a member types its name. For example, they type `r!register Myth` and then it gives them the "Myth" role.

```js
const list = [
  'Eliminaries', //Eliminaries
  'Myth', //Myth
  'Squad of Skilled', //Squad of Skilled
  'Brazil Printer Mafia', //Brazil Printer Mafia
  'Communist Party of Nevada', //Communist Party Of Nevada
  'Sando Gang', //Sando Gang
  'Century Street Gang', //Century Street Gang
  'Liberators', //Liberators
  'Celestial Blue', //Celestial Blue
  'Gang Of The Mists', //Gang Of The Mists
  'Phoenix Core', //Phoenix Core
  'Crimson', //Crimson
];

// get a collection of roles that have names included in the list array
let gangroles = message.guild.roles.cache.filter((role) =>
  list.includes(role.name),
);
// remove every matching roles
gangroles.each((r) => {
  message.member.roles.remove(r.id).catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

This is for removing roles but I'm having a hard time making the adding role by typing its name off the array.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's not working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Im getting this in console: https://imgur.com/a/lPx2jYr

It keeps spamming the chat and I did this:
    const existing = users.filter((u) => u.name === message.member.user.tag)[0];
        for (word in list) {
            if (args[0].includes(word))
                if (existing) {
                    return message.channel.send("You have already registered.");
                }

         message.member.roles.add(word.id).catch(err => console.log(err))

Comment: `for.. in` returns the index of the spoken of element that is currently being checked if speaking of arrays. You should replace it with `for.. of`.

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't work and does the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the role name provided by the user is in the list first, then you can use the [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method to check if the role exists on the server. If it exists, you can add it to the user.

The following code should work:

```js
const list = [
  'Eliminaries', //Eliminaries
  'Myth', //Myth
  'Squad of Skilled', //Squad of Skilled
  'Brazil Printer Mafia', //Brazil Printer Mafia
  'Communist Party of Nevada', //Communist Party Of Nevada
  'Sando Gang', //Sando Gang
  'Century Street Gang', //Century Street Gang
  'Liberators', //Liberators
  'Celestial Blue', //Celestial Blue
  'Gang Of The Mists', //Gang Of The Mists
  'Phoenix Core', //Phoenix Core
  'Crimson', //Crimson
];

// args[0] is the role name provided by the user
const roleName = list.find((item) => item.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLowerCase());

if (!roleName)
  return message.channel.send(`It looks like \`${args[0]}\` is not a valid role name`);

const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === roleName);

if (!role)
  return message.channel.send(`Role \`${args[0]}\` looks like a valid role name but it does not exist`);

message.member.roles
  .add(role.id)
  .then((updatedMember) => {
    message.channel.send(`Role \`${roleName}\` is added to ${message.author}`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error adding the role');
  });
```